# python won't stop looping regardless what i do

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, break

So as the title states, I have no clue how to fix a somewhat seemingly simply issue with a break statement, no matter where I put the `break` statement it won't stop the loop and for the life of me can't see why. If anyone could give some insight into what I'm not seeing that would be fantastic.

```
    def AddContacts():
        contact = list(add.keys())[-1] + str(1)

    while True:
        try:
            name = input("Enter name here: ")
            number = input("Enter number here: ")
            email = input("Enter email here: ")
            # add data to contacts
            add[contact] = {
                "Name": f"{name}",
                "Number": f"{number}",
                "Email": f"{email}"
            }
            print(f"You have now added a new contact with these details:\n{add[contact]}\nYour contact book now "
                  f"includes: {add}")
        except ValueError:
            print("Wrong input. Please enter a correct format.\n")
        else:
            break
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
do_loop = True
while do_loop:
    try:
        name = input("Enter name here: ")
        number = input("Enter number here: ")
        email = input("Enter email here: ")
        # add data to contacts
        add[contact] = {
            "Name": f"{name}",
            "Number": f"{number}",
            "Email": f"{email}",
        }
        print(
            f"You have now added a new contact with these details:\n{add[contact]}\nYour contact book now "
            f"includes: {add}"
        )
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong input. Please enter a correct format.\n")
    else:
        do_loop = False
    do_loop = False
```

Comment: i replaced do_loop with x, x under the else statement is claiming to not be used? everything else is the same as on here...so like else: x = False isn't being used apparently?

Comment: if the x under the else statement is claiming to not be used it means that there is an exception inside the try block, since the else statement is reachable only when the try section is executed without errors. I tried to copy your code by replacing only the part where you add the contact created to the add object, and it works correctly (also the version with break)

Comment: interesting, thank you for explaining it like that

Comment: issue is i still have no idea how to find the issue within the try block as no issues are showing in the output, i also noticed in the output that it shows "email" before the added person...is that normal?

Comment: could you please provide the code you got working exactly? no matter what i do following your comment it's 1. not working still and 2. in output there is an "email1" showing up which is confusing me as i never made an email1